# Pointer of pointer arithmetic?

Tags: c, pointers, math

I understand how the arithmetic of pointers works, but I have doubts about the one of the pointer of pointer:
If I have this code:

```
    int x;
    int* ptr = &x;
    int** ptrptr = &ptr;
```

On a standard Windows system, if I do:

```
printf("%d",ptr);
ptr++;
printf("%d",ptr);
```

ptr will have a "+4" value than before, obviously because integer needs 4 bytes.

Now, if I do:

```
printf("%d",ptrptr);
ptrptr++;
printf("%d",ptrptr);
```

ptrptr will have a "+16" value than before, why? 
 I apologize if this question has already been posted but I couldn't find out, thank you.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int x;
    int* ptr = &x;
    int** ptrptr = &ptr;

    printf("Pointer: %p\nPointer of pointer: %p\n",(void*)ptr,(void*)ptrptr);
    ptr++;
    ptrptr++;
    printf("Pointer: %p\nPointer of pointer: %p\n",(void*)ptr,(void*)ptrptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Pointer: 000000000062FE44
Pointer of pointer: 000000000062FE38
Pointer: 000000000062FE48
Pointer of pointer: 000000000062FE40
```

Comment: Do not use `%d` to print pointers, use `%p` and cast them to `void *`.

Comment: What is `sizeof (int *)` on your system?

Comment: You might want to post the values you see.  I'd have expected to see a difference of 4 or 8 on Windows.

Comment: True, you're right, but arithmetically it is always a "+16 offset" (in decimal)

Comment: On my system it's 4.

Comment: Could you post the complete code which gives that difference?

Comment: Getting 8 for `((void*)++ptrptr)-((void*)&ptr)` which maches the `sizeof(int*)` 8byte of my 64 bit system, everything else would be really curious.

Comment: Check answers, I'll put the code there in order to let you see better

Comment: @AlessandroF Please don't post an answer, edit your question. It is much more readable this way.

Comment: @Gamification Pointer arithmetic on `void *` is not allowed (it probably only works because it is a gcc extension).

Comment: @AlessandroF Could you change the specifier to `%p`, cast the parameters to `void *` and update your results? Like this: `printf("Pointer: %p\nPointer of pointer: %p\n", (void*)ptr, (void*)ptrptr);`

Comment: Sure, one second please

Comment: It seems to me that the difference `62FE40` - `62FE38` is now `8` which is the desired result for 64bit platforms.

Comment: Oh, I really don't know why, sorry

Comment: Can you help me to understand why 8 anyway? I mean why the "pointer of pointer" has a 8byte offset, instaead just "ptr" has 4? Thank you

Comment: Your computer as most present computers has probably 64 bits addresses.

Comment: Using the wrong specifier invokes undefined behavior, so anything could happen. As you correctly said the difference in `ptr` and `ptr+1` is because on your system an `int` has 4 bytes. The same applies to `ptrptr` but the difference is `8` since a pointer has 8 bytes on your system.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `0x...FE40` and `0x...FE38` is `8`, **not** `16`, and 8 is the correct number of bytes of an address on a 64bit machine.

To hold an int (on your system) you need a box of 4 bytes. So to skip to the next item in memory you add 4 to the address of your initial int.

To hold a pointer_to_int (which is an address on your 64bit system) you need a box of 8 bytes.

A hint: the very numbers you are subtracting are 8-byte-long addresses:

`0x00.00.00.00.00.62.FE.40` - `0x00.00.00.00.00.62.FE.38` = `0x08`. The dots are only a visual aid.